# What is the easiest way for users to update Discord commands?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a Discord bot deployed on Heroku. The deployment method is via GitHub update. I was using Node.js and Discord.js library.

When we need to add some new commands ad hoc, I need to add:

- some data at Firebase Real-Time Database
- command inside command/name_of_command.js
- update the bot (via git push to GitHub repository)
- run deploy-commands.js script so the commands are updated

This is all fast, but I wish for total independence of:

- code and data
- me and the users

I wish that users can add in a very easy way, new commands, and that's it. What troubles me is:

- even if users can update the commands, (or update the database), someone still needs to run deploy-commands.js
- if the commands can be added to the bot dynamically, either from db or from some config file, still someone would need to call some script file each time, right?

Tell me your opinion, on what would be the easiest way for users to keep adding commands without me.

Shortly: Is there a way for a user to have a form, to submit a form and the Discord Choices are updated automatically? Or if not this, then what would be the next close solution? (focusing on the ease of use for the users - server admins).

Answer (score 0):

how about using `webhook`?.
This way, you can allow the users to update the commands directly from the `webhook`, without having to run any script files.
The `webhook` would then update the database and the `commands` accordingly. The downside of this is that it requires setting up a `webhook` for each `command`, which may not be `feasible` for all commands.

Another solution would be to have the `users submit` their `commands` via a `form` or a similar interface, which would then be stored in the `database`. The `bot` would then read the `database` and update the `commands` accordingly.

This would require more setup on the bot's side, but would be easier for the users to use.